# How to connect this laptop SATA HDD to regular desktop SATA cable?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, sata

How can I connect this laptop SATA HDD to regular desktop SATA cable? Please look at the picture for reference. I can't find any adaptors and not sure if any SATA dock has similar connector.

[image]

**EDIT:** An image of the drive with the interposer/bridge successfully removed.

[image]

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help. It was super easy and I did not think hard enough. I just took the plastic park off the HDD.  
http://imgur.com/7uKbd3Z

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on the model number of HTS543232L9A300 on that label the drive is a Hitachi Travelstar 320GB 5400 RPM SATA 2.5" laptop hard drive.

But that is definitely not a standard SATA connector; I bet that thing connected to it is some kind of laptop connector interposer/bridge. I would see if you can pull that off because I am pretty confident that beneath it there is a standard SATA connector.

Just look at these images I snagged off of a similar model on eBay; clearly comes with standard SATA.

**EDIT:** Since the original poster says the connector is part of the main logic board on the drive, another idea would be to simply purchase another logic board for the same exact model but make sure it has SATA connectors. Mind you this should be considered a **last resort effort** since sometimes the logic board connected to a drive could be fine tuned specifically for that exact disk stack. But if you feel you have no other choice, get a logic board from a similar drive & then just swap that in to see what happens.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: And the op's connectors are *sticking out*, so it might be an additional connector over a standard sata interface. Wierd, I thought that sort of thing died off with pata.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no standard sata connector. It just has connector bridge which is connected directly to the motherboard.

Comment: Given that the model number of the OP's drive matches _exactly_ the one in JakeGould's picture, I think the OP is mistaken, despite his followup. If the drive came from HGST with a different connector it would have had a different model number.  I think there's a standard SATA connector under that... thing. Grab the plastic part of the thing and start pulling and wiggling.

Comment: I'd be wary about swapping in another board. These can often contain motor calibration data that could vary across batches (or even individual drives) of the same model, and could *potentially* destroy the drive. Maybe a last-resort option.

Answer (score 3):

I had a laptop that used this type of drive too. There was a little plastic piece that turned it into a standard SATA connector. You might find one by googling `HP dv9000 hdd caddy parts`. the official HP part number should be: 434106-001. Look at these images from an Amazon post. The little plastic rectangle piece is the one you're looking for.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Yes, it would be good to have something vice versa to the connecter from the link.

Comment: oh, good point. It does look like he needs to pull off that peice instead